# List adapter with multiple cell types repeating cells

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So I have a list of different kinds of cells, and the content that should go in them. I'm trying to load each one but instead my adapter will only load so many then repeat those cells. Here is my adapter class

```
public class FormCellAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cell> {

    private final Context context;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        // All cells
        TextView questionLabel;

        // Checkbox cell
        LinearLayout checkGroup;

        // Date cell
        Button dateButton;

        // Dropdown cell
        Spinner spinner;

        // Slider cell
        SeekBar seekBar;
        TextView sliderLabel;

        // Text area cell
        EditText textArea;

        // Dropdown cell, text field cell, text field toggle cell
        EditText textField;

        // Text field toggle cell, toggle cell
        RadioGroup radioGroup;
    }

    public FormCellAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cell> cells) {
        super(context, 0, cells);

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Cell cell = getItem(position);

        final int layout = cell.getLayoutFile();
        final CellType type = cell.getCellType();

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder.questionLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionTextLabel);
            viewHolder.questionLabel.setText(cell.getQuestion());

            switch (type) {
                case CHECKBOX:
                    viewHolder.checkGroup = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkGroup);
                    break;
                case DATE:
                    viewHolder.dateButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateButton);
                    break;
                case DROPDOWN:
                    viewHolder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    viewHolder.textField = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textField);
                    break;
                case SLIDER:
                    viewHolder.seekBar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
                    viewHolder.sliderLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sliderLabel);
                    break;
                case TEXTAREA:
                    viewHolder.textArea = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textArea);
                    break;
                case TEXTFIELD:
                    viewHolder.textField = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textField);
                    break;
                case TEXTFIELDTOGGLE:
                    viewHolder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                    viewHolder.textField = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textField);
                case TOGGLE:
                    viewHolder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                    break;
            }

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // This will be filled in later, populating the labels and whatever else needs done.
        switch (type) {
            case CHECKBOX:

                break;
            case DATE:

                break;
            case DROPDOWN:

                break;
            case SLIDER:

                break;
            case TEXTAREA:

                break;
            case TEXTFIELD:

                break;
            case TEXTFIELDTOGGLE:

            case TOGGLE:

                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I've trimmed out a lot of code from this because I figured I might as well just start over. Before it would randomly pick what cells went in, and often the cells that would be at the top would be different after scrolling down then back up.

Any ideas why I'm not seeing all of my cells in here, and why they're repeating themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Override getCount() to return the number of cells you want to display.

Comment: It's already returning the correct number of cells, just not the correct cell. That method is taken care of in the super anyway.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you're using `ViewHolder` pattern . the goal of using ViewHolder pattern is to inflate layout file jsut once and then reuse that inflated view in the next list items . in order to inflate different layout file you have to inflate them every time that layout file changes in `getView` .
your `getView` Method will look like this :

```
        // All cells
        TextView questionLabel;

        // Checkbox cell
        LinearLayout checkGroup;

        // Date cell
        Button dateButton;

        // Dropdown cell
        Spinner spinner;

        // Slider cell
        SeekBar seekBar;
        TextView sliderLabel;

        // Text area cell
        EditText textArea;

        // Dropdown cell, text field cell, text field toggle cell
        EditText textField;

        // Text field toggle cell, toggle cell
        RadioGroup radioGroup;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Cell cell = getItem(position);

    final int layout = cell.getLayoutFile();
    final CellType type = cell.getCellType();

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, parent, false);

        questionLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionTextLabel);
        questionLabel.setText(cell.getQuestion());

        switch (type) {
            case CHECKBOX:
                checkGroup = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.checkGroup);
                break;
            case DATE:
                dateButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dateButton);
                break;
            case DROPDOWN:
                spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                textField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textField);
                break;
            case SLIDER:
                seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
                sliderLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sliderLabel);
                break;
            case TEXTAREA:
                textArea = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textArea);
                break;
            case TEXTFIELD:
                textField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textField);
                break;
            case TEXTFIELDTOGGLE:
                radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                textField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textField);
            case TOGGLE:
                radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                break;
        }

    // This will be filled in later, populating the labels and whatever else needs done.
    switch (type) {
        case CHECKBOX:

            break;
        case DATE:

            break;
        case DROPDOWN:

            break;
        case SLIDER:

            break;
        case TEXTAREA:

            break;
        case TEXTFIELD:

            break;
        case TEXTFIELDTOGGLE:

        case TOGGLE:

            break;
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that cause memory leaks? That's why I switched to the ViewHolder. Also, Android gives the warning "Unconditional inflation from view adapter" when using this method, telling me to use the View Holder pattern instead.

Comment: @CodyHarness just deny that warning . you wont be able reach your goal with ViewHolder pattern .

Comment: Well this has somewhat fixed my problem. The cells all come up in the correct order and never shift around, but whenever I set the value of any control then scroll it out of sight it clears the value since it rebuilds the view when it comes back into sight. Any ideas on how to go around that?